# Python using itertools and multi-threading to find out the password in excel

Tags: python, multithreading

Final update:

Once the password correct other passwords can open the excel so if divide the `Process` into 4, when the first password mathed other 3 `Process` will put the nearly password to open the excel(at this time the excel has already opend) so there will show 4 correct password.

```
def mainstep(file,passwords,threadname):
    time_begin = time.time()
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False
    for password in passwords:
        try:
            excel.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, Password=password)
        except pywintypes.com_error:
            excel.Application.Quit()
            #print('Threadname '+str(threadname)+' Error '+str(password))
            pass
        else:
            print('Success '+str(password))
            excel.Application.Quit()
            time_end=time.time()
            print('time:{} seconds '.format(time_end-time_begin))
            break
```

Update the codes based on the answer:

```
def mainstep(file,passwords):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False
    for password in passwords:
        try:
            excel.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, Password=password)
        except pywintypes.com_error:
            pass
        else:
            print('Success '+password)
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 4
    groups = [passw[i::NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES] for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)]
    for group in groups:
        p = Process(target=mainstep, args=(path,group))
        p.start()
```

i set the excel passoword is 'wulong' then when i run the codes it output the result are:

```
Success wwwwww
Success wwwwwu
Success wwwwwl
Success wwwwwo
```

It's really really confused.

============================================================

I am trying to find out the password of an excel workbook.

First I use `itertools` to create my password dictionary

```
import itertools,os,sys
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import pywintypes
import threading
import pythoncom
# setting the password words
path='C:/Users/M_Seas/Desktop/file.xlsx'
words='lowung'
passw=[]
pw=itertools.product(words,repeat=6)
# write all combination into dic and list
dic=open("password.txt","a")
for word in pw:
    dic.write(''.join(word)+'\n')
dic.close()
with open("password.txt","r") as f:
    for word in f.readlines():
        passw.append(word.strip('\n'))
```

Then the next step is to use these combination to open the excel workbook:

```
def mainstep(path):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False
    for i in passw:
        try:
            excel.Workbooks.Open(path, False, True, None, Password=i)
        except pywintypes.com_error:
            print('Error '+i)
        else:
            print('Success '+i)
            break
```

But this way is too slow to find out the correct key, so I use `threading` to speed it up.

I want to divide it into 5 threads:

```
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=mainstep, args=(path,))
    t.start()
>>Error llllll
Error llllll
Error llllll
Error llllll
Error llllll
Error lllllo
Error lllllo
Error lllllo
Error lllllo
Error lllllo
```

Finally I found, that the 5 threads are all checking the same passwords. In which way can I really split the passwords into 5 parts and then process them with multiple threads to make it speed up??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `threading` does not help you here. The key is [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). As stated in this [detailed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python), `threading` is used to make responsive applications, while not able to use multiple CPU cores to run in parrallel.

`multiprocessing` is used to parrallelize your code using multiple CPU cores, to make your program run faster.

To use `multiprocessing` you have to split up your combinations by grouping all password combinations in `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES` parts and start one process for each group.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

passw = [ ... ] # your list of passwords, obtained by reading your file
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 4 # the number of processes you want to use

# split your passw list in NUMBER_OF_CORES parts
groups = [passw[i::NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES] for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)]

# spawn processes
for group in groups:
    p = Process(target=mainstep, args=(path,group))
    p.start()
```

You have to change your `mainstep` function to take an additional argument `passwords` to be processed, e.g.

```
def mainstep(path, passwords):
    # ... something ...
    for password in passwords:
        # open excel and try password
```

Comment: In ```groups = [ls[i::NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES] for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)]``` what does the ```ls``` means??

Comment: Ah my bad. It refers to `pasw`.

Comment: I modify the codes and run it but it get the multi-correct keys as results, what cause it??? I update the codes at the beginning of the question

Comment: Can you try reading something from the excel file in `mainstep`? Is the password really set? Is Excel already open?

Comment: Finally it run successfully but the process time is really the same between using ```Process``` or just run ```mainstep```, i am not sure why cause it

Comment: Maybe the multiple excel processes block each other, e.g. you can't have multiple excel instances up at the same time. Also, how many cpu cores do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211985/discussion-between-m-sea-and-erich).